# CONVERT- SQL Query

Tags: sql, join, type-conversion, sql-function

```
select sd.SasId, s.SiteId from db1.Site s
  left join db2.SasData sd on Convert(Numeric(6), s.SiteId) = sd.ShipId
```

Data Type:

SiteId - nvarchar(16)

ShipId - numeric(6)

Both SiteId and ShipId are the same entities but are of different datatypes and from different databases. I am receiving 'Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric' when I run the above query. Please help.

Comment: sounds like `siteid` has something in it besides numeric data.. try converting `shipid` to nvarchar instead

Comment: You should convert the other column to nvarchar instead of converting the nvarchar to numeric. It's hard to tell what is the problem without looking at the data, but converting to a string should solve it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select sd.SasId, s.SiteId from db1.Site s
  left join db2.SasData sd on s.SiteId = Convert(nvarchar(16), sd.ShipId)
```

Try converting ShipId to nvarchar(16).